# How to combine Likes for same content available in two languages on bilingual site

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, google-plus-one

I have a bilingual site where the content and description is available in both english and french. i.e.:

Same picture here available at

http://www.visualise.ca/#!/anne-au-cherry (english version)

http://fr.www.visualise.ca/#!/anne-au-cherry (french version)

They have both their own Google Plus One and Facebook Like button. The problem I'm facing is that when a visitor Likes for example the french version of this content. We can't see this Like appear in the counter on the english version. I suspect this is because the URL is different right?

But the Google plus one button does combine the +1 of both content. If you click on the +1 button of the french version it will show as if on the english version also.

I didn't configure anything and I don't know how the plusone button does the magic but I would like to know if there is a way to do the same for the Facebook Like button and somehow link content even though the language and the pages are different since it is the picture the visitor likes not the title, the url of its description you see. It would be amazing not to split the Likes.

Thank you

Comment: just put the same url for the fb like button on both versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the same url for the fb like button on both versions like aruss suggested in his comment.